# Git gets stuck during Quick Instructions in Rocket-chip

Tags: git, github, rocket-chip

When I try the **Quick Instructions** in [rocket-chip](https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-chip), it gets stuck.

After `git submodule update --init --recursive`, there is no more response, showing only:

```sh
Submodule 'fsf-binutils-gdb' (git://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git) registered for path 'fsf-binutils-gdb'
Submodule 'riscv-gnu-toolchain' (https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain.git) registered for path 'riscv-gnu-toolchain'
Submodule 'riscv-isa-sim' (https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-sim.git) registered for path 'riscv-isa-sim'
Submodule 'riscv-opcodes' (https://github.com/riscv/riscv-opcodes.git) registered for path 'riscv-opcodes'
Submodule 'riscv-openocd' (https://github.com/riscv/riscv-openocd.git) registered for path 'riscv-openocd'
Submodule 'riscv-pk' (https://github.com/riscv/riscv-pk.git) registered for path 'riscv-pk'
Submodule 'riscv-tests' (https://github.com/riscv/riscv-tests.git) registered for path 'riscv-tests'
Cloning into '/home/<username>/rocket-chip/rocket-tools/fsf-binutils-gdb'...
```

Is this a bug? Or how should I go through the quick start?

Thanks.

J. L.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this and started googling, but the solution turned out to be just to wait a while.  For some reason, it sits there with little network activity and then the fsf-binutils-gdb repo starts to get populated.

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways to access the binutils-gdb.git. You should rm the `rocket-tools` and re-download it. Then modify the `.gitmodules`, change the link of binutils-gdb.git into starting with https, rather than git. This may make the command `git submodule update --init --recursive` work.